# Register new module as a REST API in python-flask dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Consider I have this following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    return 'hello'

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I run the code and the server starts with these two API endpoints.

Now, I want to register one more endpoint in the same flask app without restarting the currently server, so that any transactions going on the existing endpoints are not interrupted.

Is there a way I can register a new endpoint with closing/restarting the server on the same flask app?

Answer (score 0):

You can register new rules at any point in your code using Flasks [`add_url_rule()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) function. This function is actually called by the `route()` decorator as well.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

Comment: I still don't see it running.
I created a new module as the way you said and run that parallel to the running server. It doesn't register the new URL. I get  Not Found error.

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. You wrote that you wanted to dynamically register a new endoint, which would work with my code. Not that you want a complete different programm to register an endpoint in another Flask app....

Comment: I'm new to flask so might not be able to express myself clearly.
The above two functions are in my one python script. The server is running at localhost. My question is, can I make another function like above and register the endpoint on the same server without stopping the currently running server?

Comment: and please note, I want to add new endpoint in the same flask app.